# In the Azure Python SDK, is it possible to generate SAS tokens specific to a ServiceBus topic?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python, sas-token

I'm using Python 3.8 and azure-servicebus v0.50.3.  I would like to generate a read-only SAS token for each topic i create.  I have figured out so far I can create the topics like so ...

```
sbs = ServiceBusService(service_namespace,
                        shared_access_key_name=key_name,
                        shared_access_key_value=key_value)
...

sbs.create_topic(name)
```

However, I'm unclear how (or if it's even possible) to use the existing API to generate a SAS token for each topic I create.  The documentation online seems to imply this isn't possible but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news and bad news.  While there are certainly ways to generate SAS tokens per topic, I don't believe you'll be able to so with the API you're using.  ServiceBusService via control_client is basically our "double-legacy" SDK and is both very dated and effectively deprecated.

That said, I would point you at our current [azure-mgmt-servicebus](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-servicebus/) package.  With it you can [create topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topics_operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--parameters--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) in a similar fashion, but more important to your purposes you can [create an authorization rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topics_operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-authorization-rule-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--authorization-rule-name--rights--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) (you'd likely want to give it only [Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.models.accessrights?view=azure-python) rights) and then [access the topic's keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topics_operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#list-keys-resource-group-name--namespace-name--topic-name--authorization-rule-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) to programmatically utilize them if needed.

To be honest, I wasn't sure if you were referring to SAS keys colloquially as tokens (Frankly I flip the naming constantly) so to cover all my bases, I'll also detail below how you'd turn the key into a transient token, but if you don't need this, you can skip the next paragraph.

While there isn't an official built-in utility to generate SAS tokens from a SAS key, in the hope that this is a workable approach, let me provide some breadcrumbs to what this would look like [here](https://gist.github.com/KieranBrantnerMagee/b20c24ab916d4b7b6e992f5d9db258da).  (This demonstrates using a SAS Key to generate and then authenticate our up-coming-GA-version with a SAS Token, you'd take as much or as little of this as you need, but the key for your purposes would be `generate_sas_token`)

Don't hesitate to shout if any clarity is needed or if I've misunderstood your issue, I'd also mention [our github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/) if you run into any problems in the future. (full disclaimer, am a maintainer for this sdk)

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm happy to transition away from the deprecated SDK, just have a couple of questions about that.  Previously, ServiceBusService required a namespace, shared access key name, and shared access key value.  In your code example here -- https://gist.github.com/KieranBrantnerMagee/b20c24ab916d4b7b6e992f5d9db258da, I'm not where clear where of if I'm still using that information or if I need to grab or generate other info from the Azure portal.  Does shared access key name and value still apply in the new (non-deprecated) SDK?

Comment: So, my example ONLY shows how to generate SAS tokens from SAS keys and then using them for the data-plane client.  To your point about replacing the deprecated API, unfortunately azure-mgmt-servicebus and the other ARM libraries do not support SAS, only azure-identiy credentials.  Our data plane library (azure-servicebus) will still allow SAS but the ARM side (azure-mgmt-servicebus) is trying to make azure-identity the happy path, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.servicebusmanagementclient?view=azure-python) for docs.

Comment: Quick clarification on terminology, if we use azure-identity instead of SAS, what's the right term to use to describe creating listen-only authentication when creating a service bus topic?  If we're not using SAS tokens, what are we using?

Comment: Aha, I may be able to clarify the confusion.

1. azure-identity is instead of SAS for using the `azure-mgmt-servicebus` library, which is for creating topics, creating topic SAS keys, etc. As the name implies, "management" functions.

2. for the `azure-servicebus` library, the code you use for actually sending/receiving messages with the topic, you can use listen only SAS keys (or SAS tokens derived from those keys) to authenticate.

Comment: What's the difference between the way you create the service client (ServiceBusClient) in your code sample -- https://gist.github.com/KieranBrantnerMagee/b20c24ab916d4b7b6e992f5d9db258da and the doc you reference -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus?view=azure-python#create-topic?  Are these just two different ways of getting to the same thing?

Comment: Apologize for interruption here but I am also a bit confused between legacy SDK and updated one. Not sure if this link [https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples] is applicable for updated SDK but this is as far as i can get.

Comment: Hey Dave;  I must apologize for misleading you slightly, the create_topic link should have pointed under [this client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus/management?view=azure-python), the overview is legacy.

To try and address both comments confusion, there are a few clients: 1. `azure-servicebus:0.5*`, the docs Dave linked. This library sends and receives messages and has limited management functions  2. `azure-mgmt-servicebus` is the dedicated mgmt lib, e.g. topic creation  3. `azure-servicebus:7.0` the upcoming GA release for messaging, your link liam

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think I stumbled upon the right data before you posted the link so all is well.  However I am struggling with how to find the number of topics per namespace if you have know off the top of your head -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285330/in-the-azure-functions-python-sdk-how-do-i-get-the-number-of-topics-for-a-given

Comment: Hey Dave, I notice a kind soul has chimed in there but I'll echo their accurate response here as well for progeny; that the [list_by_namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-servicebus/azure.mgmt.servicebus.operations.topicsoperations?view=azure-python#list-by-namespace-resource-group-name--namespace-name--skip-none--top-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) function will likely do what you want.