# In the Azure functions Python SDK, how do I get the number of topics for a given namespace?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm using Python 3.8 with azure-mgmt-servicebus= v. 1.0.0.  I would like to get the number of topics for a given namespace.  I have tried the below ...

```
credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret, tenant=self._tenant)
        sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, self._subscription)
         ...
        topics = sb_client.topics.list_by_namespace(
                resource_group_name=self._resource_group_name,
                namespace_name=namespace
            )
            num_topics = 0
            while topics.current_page:
                num_topics += topics.current_page.count
                topics.next
            logging.info("num topics: %s", num_topics)
```

My "num_topics" consistently comes back with zero, despite the fact I have verified that my connection is being made (I can create a topic with the same connection) and I can see many topics for the given information in the Azure portal.  I'm thinking I'm not using the API properly but am unsure where things are falling apart.  How do I get the number of topics for a given namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the number of the topics for a given service bus namespace, you could use the code below.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient

subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"
rg_name = "<resource-group-name>"

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
client_id = "<client-id>"
client_secret = "<client-secret>"

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
topics = sb_client.topics.list_by_namespace(resource_group_name= rg_name, namespace_name= "servicebusname")

num_topics = 0
for topic in topics:
    num_topics += 1
print(num_topics)
```

[image]

Check the topics in the portal, the result is correct:

[image]

**Update:**

If you don't want to use the loop, you could convert the `topics` to a list, then use the `len()` function.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.servicebus import ServiceBusManagementClient

subscription_id = "<subscription-id>"
rg_name = "<resource-group-name>"

tenant_id = "<tenant-id>"
client_id = "<client-id>"
client_secret = "<client-secret>"

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=client_id, secret=client_secret, tenant=tenant_id)
sb_client = ServiceBusManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
topics = sb_client.topics.list_by_namespace(resource_group_name= rg_name, namespace_name= "servicebusname")

testlist = list(topics)
print(len(testlist))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a more O(1) way to retrieve this information?  I notice that if I have 2000 topics, this will loop 2000 times and run more O(n).  Seems like this information would be more easily retrievable.

Comment: If the concern is the `num_topics +=` loop, I'd mention to just use `len()` instead; I would expect it to work properly with the value returned from list_by_namespace.  Of course, don't hesitate to shout if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Kibrantn Yes, you are right, just use `list()` first, then use `len()`, we could not use `len()` on a `SBTopicPaged` directly.